# Pyspark: applying kmeans on different groups of a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, pyspark, k-means

Using Pyspark I would like to apply kmeans separately on groups of a dataframe and not to the whole dataframe at once. For the moment I use a for loop which iterates on each group, applies kmeans and appends the result to another table. But having a lot of groups makes it time consuming. Anyone could help me please??
Thanks a lot!

```
for customer in customer_list:
    temp_df = togroup.filter(col("customer_id")==customer)
    df = assembler.transform(temp_df)
    k = 1
    while (k < 5 & mtrc < width):
        k += 1
        kmeans = KMeans(k=k,seed=5,maxIter=20,initSteps=5)
        model = kmeans.fit(df)
        mtric = 1 - model.computeCost(df)/ttvar
        a = model.transform(df)select(cols)
        allcustomers = allcustomers .union(a)
```

Comment: Please attach the code you are working with to the question.

Comment: This is not a dumb question, so I don't understand the downvote. I never tried it on clustering but it seems window functions might work here.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution using pandas_udf. A pure spark or scala solution is preferred and yet to be offered. 
Assume my data is

```
import pandas as pd
df_pd = pd.DataFrame([['cat1',10.],['cat1',20.],['cat1',11.],['cat1',21.],['cat1',22.],['cat1',9.],['cat2',101.],['cat2',201.],['cat2',111.],['cat2',214.],['cat2',224.],['cat2',99.]],columns=['cat','val'])
df_sprk = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
```

First solve the problem in pandas:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2,random_state=0)

def skmean(kmeans,x):
    X = np.array(x)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    return(kmeans.predict(X))
```

You can apply skmean() to a panda data frame (to make sure it works properly):

```
df_pd.groupby('cat').apply(lambda x:skmean(kmeans,x)).reset_index()
```

To apply the function to pyspark data frame, we use pandas_udf. But first define a schema for the output data frame:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType(
       [StructField('cat',StringType(),True),
        StructField('clusters',ArrayType(IntegerType()))])
```

Convert the function above to a pandas_udf:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType  

@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def skmean_udf(df):
    result = pd.DataFrame(
             df.groupby('cat').apply(lambda x: skmean(kmeans,x))
    result.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
    return(result)
```

You can use the function as follows:

```
df_spark.groupby('cat').apply(skmean_udf).show()
```

Comment: Is that really faster as the pure pyspark solution posted in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a second solution which is I think is slightly better than the last one. The idea is to use `groupby()` together with`collect_list()` and write a udf that takes a list as input and generates the clusters. Continuing with `df_spark` in the other solution we write:

```
df_flat = df_spark.groupby('cat').agg(F.collect_list('val').alias('val_list'))
```

Now we write the udf function:

```
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def skmean(x):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0)
    X = np.array(x).reshape(-1,1)  
    kmeans.fit(X)
    clusters = kmeans.predict(X).tolist()
    return(clusters)
clustering_udf = F.udf(lambda arr : skmean(arr), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Then apply the udf to the flattened dataframe:

```
df = df_flat.withColumn('clusters', clustering_udf(F.col('val')))
```

Then you can use `F.explode()` to convert the list to a column.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df = df_flat.withColumn('clusters', clustering_udf(F.col('val_list')))`?

Comment: @pmjn6 At least in your previous answer, if one has pyarrow installed, the pandas method might be slightly faster. This method would get expensive really fast as the size of the dataset increases.
I think Eva's original method might be the best since it is done entierly in pyspark. Although the for loops are clunky and ineffecient.