# How to run multiple k means clustering and use groupBy in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset like so:

```
|Seq_key|   |Class_id|  |value|
Seq_key 1   Class_id 1  value 1
Seq_key 1   Class_id 2  value 2
Seq_key 1   Class_id 3  value 3
Seq_key 1   Class_id 4  value 4
Seq_key 1   Class_id 5  value 5
Seq_key 1   Class_id 6  value 6
Seq_key 2   Class_id 1  value 1
Seq_key 2   Class_id 2  value 2
Seq_key 2   Class_id 3  value 3
Seq_key 2   Class_id 4  value 4
Seq_key 2   Class_id 5  value 5
Seq_key 2   Class_id 6  value 6
Seq_key 2   Class_id 7  value 7
Seq_key 3   Class_id 1  value 1
Seq_key 3   Class_id 2  value 2
Seq_key 3   Class_id 3  value 3
Seq_key 3   Class_id 4  value 4
Seq_key 3   Class_id 5  value 5
Seq_key 3   Class_id 6  value 6
Seq_key 3   Class_id 7  value 7
Seq_key 3   Class_id 8  value 8
```

The `Class_ids` and `values` for each `Seq_key` are mutually exclusive.
I apply k-means clustering for each `Seq_key` and find the optimal number of clusters, centroids etc such that the outputs for each `Seq_key` are like so:

```
|Seq_key|   |Class id|  |Cluster|  |Centroid|
Seq_key 1   Class_id 1     1         128
Seq_key 1   Class_id 2     2         56
Seq_key 1   Class_id 3     3         100
Seq_key 1   Class_id 4     1         128
Seq_key 1   Class_id 5     1         128
Seq_key 1   Class_id 6     4         72
Seq_key 2   Class_id 1     1         5.5
Seq_key 2   Class_id 2     1         5.5
Seq_key 2   Class_id 3     2         3.4
Seq_key 2   Class_id 4     3         1.7
Seq_key 2   Class_id 5     1         5.5
Seq_key 2   Class_id 6     2         3.4
Seq_key 2   Class_id 7     2         3.4
Seq_key 3   Class_id 1     4         500
Seq_key 3   Class_id 2     1         700
Seq_key 3   Class_id 3     3         274
Seq_key 3   Class_id 4     2         189
Seq_key 3   Class_id 5     2         189
Seq_key 3   Class_id 6     4         500
Seq_key 3   Class_id 7     1         700
Seq_key 3   Class_id 8     3         274
```

Currently, I am looping through each `Seq_key` manually and applying the k-means algorithm from the `pyspark.ml.clustering` library. But this is clearly inefficient as the number of `seq_keys` increases to tens of thousands. Also, I am not properly exploiting the distributed computing of spark.

The `Seq_key` are mutually exclusive, so they cannot be clustered with other `Seq_keys`
Is there a way to achieve my output via a `groupBy` like method in the `ml` libraries?
Even just calculating the centroids grouped by the `Seq_key` would suffice.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to improve runtime by horizontal parallelism i.e. running multiple Spark jobs in parallel, like so:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

def run_kmeans(seqid, data=sens):

    df_tmp=data.filter(col('SEQ_ID')==seqid)\
        .select('SEQ_KEY','CLASS_ID','value')
    for c in df_tmp.columns:
        if c in FEATURE_COLS:
            df_tmp=df_tmp.withColumn(c, df_tmp[c].cast("float"))
    df_tmp=df_tmp.na.drop()
    vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=FEATURE_COLS, outputCol="features")
    vector_df = vecAssembler.transform(df_tmp)
    bkm = BisectingKMeans().setK(4).setSeed(1).setFeaturesCol("features")
    model = bkm.fit(vector_df)
    cluster=model.transform(vector_df).drop('features')

    return cluster

pool = ThreadPool(cpu_count())
fleet_clusters = pool.map(run_kmeans, fleets)
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I will try it out.
Can you explain what the `df` arg in the `run_kmeans` function is?
Im assuming that the `pool.map` function takes in the contents of the list `fleets` and runs the `run_kmeans` function on its contents parallelly. That would be the `seqid` arg as the input. But what is `df` ?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo should have been `df_tmp`

Comment: Another silly question. the `seqid` is an iterator from the for loop in my solution. Do I still need to run a for loop with your method? 
Also, the `df_tmp` is a dummy data frame created inside the function. Should we pass that as in input arg to the `run_kmeans` function?

Comment: fixed the errors now, does this answer your question above?

Comment: When i run the code I get the error: `Can't pickle <function run_kmeans at 0x7f077ee30d40>: attribute lookup run_kmeans on __main__ failed`

My spark version is 2.4.6

Comment: I finally got it to work with your method after digging into `multiprocessing` and `Pool` and `ThreadPool`. Your library definition was wrong. It had to be `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`. I took the liberty to correct that in your post. I was able to reduce the time by 22%. Thank you for the solution! :)

Comment: Great, glad it helped in the end

Answer (score 0):

So I implemented a make-shift solution getting ideas from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224479/pyspark-applying-kmeans-on-different-groups-of-a-dataframe).

I collected a distinct list of the `Seq_keys` and then manually for-looped through each one and applied the pyspark kmeans method like so:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import BisectingKMeans
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler    
fleets=list(sens.select('SEQ_KEY').distinct().toPandas()['SEQ_KEY'])
for seqid in fleets:
    df_tmp=sens.filter(col('SEQ_ID')==seqid)\
    .select('SEQ_KEY','CLASS_ID','value')
    for c in df_tmp.columns:
        if c in FEATURE_COLS:
            df_tmp=df_tmp.withColumn(c, df_tmp[c].cast("float"))
    df_tmp=df_tmp.na.drop()
    vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=FEATURE_COLS, outputCol="features")
    vector_df = vecAssembler.transform(df_tmp)
    bkm = BisectingKMeans().setK(4).setSeed(1).setFeaturesCol("features")
    model = bkm.fit(vector_df)
    cluster=model.transform(vector_df).drop('features')
    fleet_clusters.append(cluster)

final_clustered_fleet=reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, fleet_clusters)
```

I'm disregarding the centroids for now. Just getting the cluster information would suffice.

This is clearly dirty and inefficient. In fact, it took about 8 hours for my job to run because of the `collect` methods invoked by the kmeans function. 90% of my worker nodes were idle.
It would be great if there was a more efficient way to do this preferably leveraging the multiple worker nodes afforded by spark.