# VectorAssembler forces data into the Driver. How can we avoid that?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, vectorization

When using the `pyspark.ml.feature` libraries, the [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features) is used to transform a list of columns into a single vector column that is conducive for feature extractions and applying ML models, etc...
However, the `transform` function, by design, implements the `collect` function which brings all the data to the Driver.
I see a lot of collect jobs in my Spark UI History

[image]

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import BisectingKMeans
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=FEATURE_COLS, outputCol="features")
vector_df = vecAssembler.transform(df)
bkm = BisectingKMeans().setK(4).setSeed(1).setFeaturesCol("features")
model = bkm.fit(vector_df)
cluster=model.transform(vector_df).drop('features')
```

**DAG Visualization**

[image]

This counteracts the efficiency of spark executions. Is there a counterpart to VectorAssembler or is there a way to use it while still maintaining the distributed computing that spark gives us?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet highlighting your transformation logic. Also please share the query plan of one of these jobs.

Comment: @vatsalmevada I have added the code as you requested. For the Query plan, did you mean the DAG visualization from the spark UI?

Comment: yes. I meant DAG visualization.

Comment: @vatsalmevada I have added the DAG Visualization

Comment: It's not the fault of VectorAssembler. The Spark UI suggests that it's BisectingKmeans that does the `collect`.

Comment: @thentangler, which Spark version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a very limited understanding of Spark MLLib.
However, looking at the code it seems that the `collect` operation that you are referring to is part of the `BisectingKMeans` algorithm (as pointed out by @mck in one of the comments).

```
  private def summarize(
      d: Int,
      assignments: RDD[(Long, VectorWithNorm)],
      distanceMeasure: DistanceMeasure): Map[Long, ClusterSummary] = {
    assignments.aggregateByKey(new ClusterSummaryAggregator(d, distanceMeasure))(
        seqOp = (agg, v) => agg.add(v),
        combOp = (agg1, agg2) => agg1.merge(agg2)
      ).mapValues(_.summary)
      .collect().toMap
  }
```

Reference: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.6/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/BisectingKMeans.scala#L304

Looking at the above snippet it doesn't seem that this operation is collecting the entire data on the driver and also I don't think that there is much we can do to avoid this collect operation.

Note that I have picked the above code pointer from the most recent version on Spark master branch. Depending on your spark version the line number could be different.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, because the OP didn't call `model.summarize` in the example code

Comment: Looking at the code (on latest Spark master branch), `summarize` method is a private method being invoked internally from `runWithWeight` method which gets invoked when the BisectingKMeans algorithm is invoked from `run`. Also, I checked looked around line no `304` as we can see in the screenshot shared in the question. We can get more accurate code pointer if we get precise the Spark version.

Comment: @vatsalmevada Thank you for replying. My Spark version is 2.4.6. 
Ok so the BisectingKMeans method is the one that is invoking the `collect` function. Can we design it such that it uses lazy execution?
But it is good to know that it does not collect the data to the driver. It was my understanding that the `collect` function does that. 
Thank You!

Comment: @thentangler, it does collect the data on the driver. What I meant was that looks like it is not collecting the entire data to the driver (which could give OOM on the driver) but it only collects necessary summary details which might be required as part of BusectingKMeans algorithm. Is your job slowing down drastically due to this collect operation?

Comment: Updated the link in the answer to point to the Spark 2.4.6 version of the code. Looks like with Spark 2.4.6 code the line number of collect operation is exactly the same as seem om the screenshot i.e. 304.

Comment: Ah i see. 
Yeah that seems pretty inefficient distributed computing-wise. Are there spark ML libraries that do not use the `collect` method? 
As to your question, my job does slow down drastically, since it is mainly operating in the driver node, even though I have 9 other worker nodes. They are faily idle.

Comment: I basically implemented a solution to my question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66451897/how-to-run-multiple-k-means-clustering-and-use-groupby-in-pyspark
I was forced to use a for loop but the collect method is further slowing things down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229640/discussion-between-vatsal-mevada-and-thentangler).